# Isempty(range(cell1,cell2))

Tags: excel, vba, range, cells

I encounter a problem with one of my code and I hope that one of you can rescue me.

here is my code :

```
Private Sub cmdrecherche_Click()
Dim db As Range
Dim ligne As Integer
Dim L As Long
Dim Cd As Long
Dim Cf As Long
Dim maxc As Long
Dim maxl As Long
Dim cardispo As Integer

Set dispo = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Dispo")
Set booking = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("booking")

maxc = dispo.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
maxl = dispo.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

For Cd = 5 To maxc
If Format(CDate(dispo.Cells(1, Cd).Value), "mm-dd-yyyy") = Format(CDate      (txtdepart), "mm-dd-yyyy") Then
    For Cf = 5 To maxc
        If Format(CDate(dispo.Cells(1, Cf).Value), "mm-dd-yyyy") = Format(CDate(txtfin), "mm-dd-yyyy") Then
            For L = 2 To maxl
                If IsEmpty(Range(dispo.Cells(L, Cd), dispo.Cells(L, Cf))) Then
                cardispo = dispo.Range("A" & L).Value
                listcar.AddItem cardispo
                End If
            Next L
        End If
    Next Cf
End If
Next Cd

End Sub
```

I get from a form 2 dates : txtdepart and txtfin. 
In the sheet "dispo", each column is a date, each line is a car.
If the car is used by someone, the cells between the 2 dates are merged and colored.

I want this code to check for each line (so for each car) if it's already used between txtdepart and txtfin. If not, i get the number of the car (values of the column A) and write it in the listbox "listcar" of my form.

I succeeded to make it work if only checking the txtdepart so my problem is in the range(cell1,cell2) imo.

Any idea :) ?

Comment: Are you using Excel in English?

Comment: the IsEmpty function in VBA cannot be used on ranges with multiple cells, it will always return `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem (probably not a very "beautifull" way of doin it but it works) :

```
Private Sub cmdrecherche_Click()
Dim db As Range
Dim ligne As Integer
Dim L As Long
Dim Cd As Long 'column of starting date
Dim Cf As Long 'column of ending date
Dim cdf As Long
Dim maxc As Long
Dim maxl As Long
Dim cardispo As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Dim count As Integer


Set dispo = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Dispo")
Set booking = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("booking")

With dispo
maxc = .Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
maxl = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

For Cd = 5 To maxc
    If Format(CDate(.Cells(1, Cd).Value), "mm-dd-yyyy") = Format(CDate(txtdepart), "mm-dd-yyyy") Then
        For Cf = 5 To maxc
            If Format(CDate(.Cells(1, Cf).Value), "mm-dd-yyyy") = Format(CDate(txtfin), "mm-dd-yyyy") Then
            cdf = Cf - Cd
                For L = 2 To maxl
                count = 0
                    For r = 0 To cdf
                        If IsEmpty(.Cells(L, Cd).Offset(0, r)) Then
                        count = count + 0
                        Else
                        count = count + 1
                        End If
                    Next r
                    If count = 0 Then
                    cardispo = .Range("A" & L).Value
                    listcar.AddItem cardispo
                    End If
                Next L
            End If
        Next Cf
    End If
 Next Cd
 End With

 End Sub
```

Thx for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

The line bellow can be the problem if your activesheet is somethign differente than dispo.

Change this:

```
< If IsEmpty(Range(dispo.Cells(L, Cd), dispo.Cells(L, Cf))) Then
> If IsEmpty(dispo.Range(dispo.Cells(L, Cd)) And IsEmpty(dispo.Cells(L, Cf)) Then
```

Or something like:

```
With dispo
    maxc = .Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
    maxl = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    For Cd = 5 To maxc
        If Format(CDate(.Cells(1, Cd).Value), "mm-dd-yyyy") = Format(CDate(txtdepart), "mm-dd-yyyy") Then
            For Cf = 5 To maxc
                If Format(CDate(.Cells(1, Cf).Value), "mm-dd-yyyy") = Format(CDate(txtfin), "mm-dd-yyyy") Then
                    For L = 2 To maxl
                        If IsEmpty(.Cells(L, Cd)) And IsEmpty(.Cells(L, Cf)) Then
                            cardispo = .Range("A" & L).Value
                            listcar.AddItem cardispo
                        End If
                    Next L
                End If
            Next Cf
        End If
    Next Cd
End With
```

Comment: Hi Makah :) Your first proposal returned an error, the second one works and return values but not the right one ... values returned look like only the IsEmpty(.cells(L, Cd) is tested while the cf is ignored. The othe thing is that i want the program to check ALL cells between those 2 values not only the starting date and ending date ... I keep looking into it and will update if i find a solution. Thx for your help :)

Comment: Sorry man, but i didn't test the code. Just changed your code trying to help you. :-)